# How do I find my SSH keys in Eclipse Mars?

Tags: eclipse, ssh, ssh-keys

I have an Eclipse (Mars v4.5.0) project. I set some SSH keys last night but I can't seem to find them this morning.

I looked thru the documentation, help and even did a Google search. [This video popped up](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WU9xYP_NScQ) but that's for an older version of Eclipse and the path he uses no longer applies. Any help?

### Question

> **How do I find my SSH keys in Eclipse Mars v4.5.0?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The menus have changed since that video was posted. And there is no documentation about it in the `help` or anywhere else at this moment. So, maybe, this answer might help others with the same issue in the future.

### Answer

> **Eclipse > Preferences > General > Network Connections > SSH2**